# How do I create a data type variable that can be inputed as R.raw.song_name?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to create create a varible that I can later use MediaPlayer.create()

```
private whichDataTypeHere musicResource;
...

// musicResource = R.raw.song_name
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, musicResource);
```

I want to know which data type do I have to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise it as an int array like this

```
final int[] someID = {R.raw.music, R.raw.music};
```

and then use it like

```
MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), someID [index]);
```